# Distribute half the records in two columns in sql server and then merge them

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following is my demo query:

```
select 1 as 'testrank', 'title1' as 'testtitle'
union all
select 2 as 'testrank', 'title2' as 'testtitle'
union all
select 3 as 'testrank', 'title3' as 'testtitle'
union all
select 4 as 'testrank', 'title4' as 'testtitle'
union all
select 5 as 'testrank', 'title5' as 'testtitle'
union all
select 6 as 'testrank', 'title6' as 'testtitle'
```

I want to distribute half the records, in this case 3, in two separate sections. For demo purpose, I have written below query, which is the desired output.

```
select 1 as 'testrank', 'title1' as 'testtitle', 4 as 'testrank2', 'title4' as 'testtitle2'
union all
select 2 as 'testrank', 'title2' as 'testtitle', 5 as 'testrank2', 'title5' as 'testtitle2'
union all
select 3 as 'testrank', 'title3' as 'testtitle', 6 as 'testrank2', 'title6' as 'testtitle2'
```

I tried with Pivot, using rownumber, but somehow I am not able to achieve the desired output.
Any suggestions will be welcomed.

Comment: It would be better to do this sort of formatting at a higher level than the database.

Comment: Don't do this! It's bad schema design. Worry about layout in the presentation tier, not in the data tier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ntile(2)` will group your rows in two and `row_number()` will enumerate each group. The main query joins the groups on the generated `row_number()`.

```
with C1 as
(
  select testrank,
        testtitle,
        ntile(2) over(order by testrank) as n
  from YourTable
), C2 as
(
  select testrank,
         testtitle,
         n,
         row_number() over(partition by n order by testrank) as rn
  from C1
)

select T1.testrank,
       T1.testtitle,
       T2.testrank as testrank2,
       T2.testtitle as testtitle2
from C2 as T1
  left outer join C2 as T2
    on T1.rn = T2.rn and
       T2.n = 2
where T1.n = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
CASE Ranking WHEN 1 THEN  testrank  ELSE NULL END AS A ,
CASE Ranking WHEN 1 THEN  testtitle  ELSE NULL END AS B ,
CASE Ranking WHEN 2 THEN  testrank  ELSE NULL END AS A1 ,
CASE Ranking WHEN 2 THEN  testtitle  ELSE NULL END AS B1
FROM 
(
SELECT *,NTILE(2) OVER (ORDER BY testrank) AS Ranking
FROM
(
select 1 as 'testrank', 'title1' as 'testtitle'
union all
select 2 as 'testrank', 'title2' as 'testtitle'
union all
select 3 as 'testrank', 'title3' as 'testtitle'
union all
select 4 as 'testrank', 'title4' as 'testtitle'
union all
select 5 as 'testrank', 'title5' as 'testtitle'
union all
select 6 as 'testrank', 'title6' as 'testtitle'
)AS T
)AS T1
```

Comment: You might want to edit your question, highlight the code and hit the `{}` button. Adding some explanation wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Thanks Vikas, But still not the desired result. It gives me unwanted records null for those columns which don't have records, So I am not able to get the desired output. Can you suggest some different approach.